# Create polygon area based on center of points

Tags: r, function, plot, polygon, k-means

I am quite new to R, and I would like to create a function that would take a few points, find the center of these points (like something the center of mass), and from these points draw lines that separate the groups of points, with that center in the middle of the points. Similar of making slices of pie: from center we divide the pie, to get an equal amount of parts.

The code I used for finding the centers and the plot itself is below:

```
distance <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}

find_cluster <- function(x, centers, distFun, nItter=10) {
  clusterHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  centerHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")

  for(i in 1:nItter) {
    distsToCenters <- distFun(x, centers)
    clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
    centers <- apply(x, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
    # Saving history
    clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
    centerHistory[[i]] <- centers
  }

  list(clusters=clusterHistory, centers=centerHistory)
}

a3=as.matrix(test)
centers <- a3[sample(nrow(a3), 5),]

theResult <- find_cluster(a3, centers, myEuclid, 10)
```

The plot:

```
plot(a3, col=theResult$clusters[[i]],
 main=paste("itteration:", i), xlab="x", ylab="y")
points(theResult$centers[[i]],
 cex=1, pch=19, col=1:nrow(theResult$centers[[i]]))
```

So the function should do this:

1. Take input centers
2. Find where the center of mass ( or point mass) of these points(that are centers of clusters)
3. From the main center( that is center of mass), draw lines or polygons so its separates the cluster

The test data set can be found at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yk6yq518). An example of what I would like to have is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9310Y.jpg) (and below):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this (`n` is the number of clusters you want)

```
dat <- read.table(file="test.txt", header=T)

separateClusts <- function(n, dat) {
    ## Cartesian to polar (is there a function for this?)
    cart2pol <- function(x, y, deg = FALSE) {
        r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
        theta <- atan(y / x)
        theta[x < 0] <- theta[x < 0] + pi
        theta[x >= 0 & y < 0] <- theta[x >= 0 & y < 0] + 2*pi
        if (deg) theta <- theta * 180/pi
        out <- cbind(r, theta)
        names(out) <- c("r", "theta")
        return( out )
    }

    ## Get clusters
    clusts <- kmeans(dat, n)
    centers <- clusts$centers

    ## Center of mass of clusters
    com <- matrix(colMeans(centers), ncol=2)

    ## Order them
    cent <- t(t(centers) - c(com))  # center
    pol <- cart2pol(cent[,1], cent[,2])
    ord <- sort(pol[,2], index=T)$ix
    ordered <- as.data.frame(centers[ord, ])

    ## Get midpoints
    mids <- with(ordered, {
        data.frame(
            xmid=c(x[-1] - x[-length(x)], x[1]-x[length(x)])/2 + x,
            ymid=c(y[-1] - y[-length(y)], y[1]-y[length(y)])/2 + y
        )
    })

    ## Plot
    plot(dat, col=clusts$cluster)
    points(com, col="blue", pch=16, cex=2)
    points(centers, col="red", pch=16, cex=2)
    points(mids, col="orange", pch=16, cex=2)

    ## Draw line segments
    ms <- (tmp <- t(t(mids) - c(com)))[,2] / tmp[,1]
    for (i in 1:nrow(mids))
        segments(com[,1], com[,2],
                 com[,1] + (s <- sign(mids$x[i]-com[,1]))*5,
                 com[,2] + s*ms[i]*5, col="orange", lwd=2)
}

separateClusts(5, dat)
```

[image]

The red dots are cluster centers, orange dots are midpoints between consecutive centers.  The order of the centers is determined by converting them to polar coordinates and using the angle.

Comment: But is it possible to move the golden lines to the end of the window of the graph, so that each golden line is moving from the blue spot in the middle to the each of the axes?